# How to generate random 64-digit hexadecimal number in R?

Tags: r, random, numbers, hex, blockchain

To apply in a blockchain application, I needed to generate random 64-digit hexadecimal numbers in R.

I thought that due to the capacity of computers, obtaining such an 64-digit hexadecimal number *at once* is rather cumbersome, perhaps impossible.

So, I thought that I should produce random hexadecimal numbers with rather low digits, and bring (concatenate) them together to obtain random 64-digit hexadecimal number.

I am near solution:

```
library(fBasics)
.dec.to.hex(abs(ceiling(rnorm(1) * 1e6)))
```

produces random hexadecimal numbers. The problem is that in some of the instances, I get 6-digit hexadecimal number, in some instances I get 7-digit hexadecimal number. Hence, fixing this became priority first.

Any idea?

Comment: Where is `.dec.to.hex` documented? Assuming that `dec` is an abbreviation of `decimal`, it seems like an oddly named function: surely numbers in R aren't _really_ stored in decimal? (Or is its purpose to convert *strings* in decimal to hexadecimal?)

Comment: "perhaps impossible." certainly not impossible, though it may well be awkward to spell out in R. It sounds as though you're looking for the R equivalent of Python's `hex(random.getrandbits(256))`. Is that right?

Comment: @MarkDickinson `fBasics::.dec.to.hex` reveals its content: `function (b) 
{    ans = .chcode(b, base.in = 10, base.out = 16)
    ans
}`

Comment: @MarkDickinson I do not know Python. Hence, I cannot say anything about that comparison.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply sample each digit and paste them together.

```
set.seed(123)
paste0(sample(c(0:9, LETTERS[1:6]), 64, T), collapse = '')
## [1] "4C6EF08E87F7A91E305FEBAFAB8942FEBC07C353266522374D07C1832CE5A164"
```

Comment: Very elegant and simple at the same time!

Comment: For those like me who came here looking for how to generate unique IDs, this code was perfect to insert in a for loop:
`for (i in seq(nrow(database))){
  database$uniqueID[i] <- paste0(sample(c(0:9, LETTERS), 64, T), collapse = '')
}`
many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Max argument of `.dec.to.hex()` is `.dec.to.hex(2^30.99999....9)`.
So, the question reduces to `2^30.99999=2147468763` is what power of 10?

2147468763 = 2.147468763e9

1e9 < 2.147468763e9. Hence 9th power. But, `rnorm(1)` may produce "`>5`". For safety, use 8th power (`.dec.to.hex(abs(ceiling(rnorm(1) * 1e8)))` is 7 or 8 hexa-digits. `10*7 >= 64`).

```
library(fBasics)
strtrim(paste(sapply(1:10, function(i) .dec.to.hex(abs(ceiling(rnorm(1) * 1e8)))), collapse=""), 64)
# 0397601803C22E220509810703BDE2300460EA80322F000CF50ABD0226F27009
```

10 iterations instead of 11; hence, with a little bit less operations!

```
nchar(strtrim(paste(sapply(1:10, function(i) .dec.to.hex(abs(ceiling(rnorm(1) * 1e8)))), collapse=""), 64))
# 64
```

Comment: This method will not give *uniformly* distributed hex strings: some length-64 hex strings will be much more likely to occur than others. Maybe that's what you want, but if you want a uniform distribution, I'd suggest using `runif` (plus ceiling or floor) to generate integers in the range `[0, 2**52)` (giving 13 hex digits each) instead. You only need 5 such calls to get 65 hex digits; then you can throw away the last digit.

Comment: I got awared of this. `strtrim` solution above always produces hex numbers starting with 0. But, there are 64-digit hex numbers that start with a,b,...,f. Also, subparts in 64-digit hex above starts with 0. This distrupts uniformness as you stated. I want uniform distribution, of course.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, Hunting via 5*13-1=64 is impossible since `.dec.to.hex` cannot even finish `.dec.to.hex(2^31)`, forget `.dec.to.hex(2^52)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(fBasics)
strtrim(paste(sapply(1:11, function(i) .dec.to.hex(abs(ceiling(rnorm(1) * 1e6)))), collapse=""), 64)
# 08FBFA019B4930E2AF707AFEE08A0F90D765E05757607609B0691190FC54E012
```

Let's check:

```
nchar(strtrim(paste(sapply(1:11, function(i) .dec.to.hex(abs(ceiling(rnorm(1) * 1e6)))), collapse=""), 64)) # 64
```